# Express method for economic evaluation of mechatronic devices

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, control-engineering, cost-estimation, engineering-economics

Are there quick methods for the economic evaluation of mechatronic devices that have not yet been widely adopted in industry, but are at the stage of prototyping and laboratory experiments?

Basic considerations suggest that the economic evaluation will include: the cost of materials and their production, control devices, measuring devices, assembly and commissioning.

The difficulty lies in the fact that the economic evaluation of new devices is not clearly formalized. Some of the methodologies are based on experienced service factors, but experience with new devices may not be sufficiently accumulated. It is possible to use data from devices operating in similar industrial environments, i.e. extrapolate the coefficients to new areas, but I do not know some starting points (in my case, we are talking about the economic evaluation of mechatronic devices based on parallel manipulators for the space industry).

Please excuse me if I was not clear enough. The roughness of my assessments is due to the lack of awareness in this section of the economy.

Comment: What about the embedded value of the knowledge and experience?

Comment: wouldn't it be similar to evaluating anything?

Comment: @jsotola Indeed, everything can be evaluated in this way, but these considerations are derived from simple common sense. Probably, the existing methods are a more advanced and complex version of common sense. Right? Sorry for the delay in replying, circumstances.

Comment: @SolarMike Sorry for the delay in replying, circumstances. Could you elaborate on the application of this measure in the context of mechatronic devices? Those definitions that I have met are saturated with macro- and microeconomic terminology and are contextually related to the field of company management. I cannot yet establish a bridge between them and technical devices, sorry.

Comment: You use some really big words, but what is the cost of training people to be capable of designing those devices? And the training of people capable of building those devices? And further, the cost to train people to maintain and repair...